# GitNub closes immediately — installation problem or something else?

Tags: installation, terminal, crash

I followed the steps documented on http://wiki.github.com/Caged/gitnub/installing-or-building-gitnub under ‘installing from the distribution’:

1. Launch Terminal.app.
2. `gem install open4`
3. Copy `GitNub.app` to `/Applications/*`
4. Copy the `nub` binary to `/usr/local/bin` <strike>(or somewhere else in your path)</strike>.

However, when I navigate to a git repository and enter the `nub` command, the GitNub icon appears in my Dock for a second, and then silently disappears.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like active tickets for GitNub [are here](https://activereload.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8791-gitnub/tickets?q=state%3Aopen).  These two bugs ([one](https://activereload.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8791/tickets/38-version-091-crashes-on-launch-from-nub-command), [two](https://activereload.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8791/tickets/47-crash-at-start)) describe the same symptoms.  The second suggests a fix in the thread.

No Mac so I can't test; does either one look like your issue?  Try running from Terminal to see any error messages.

Comment: Thanks, replacing `NSMinYEdge` by `CGRectMinYEdge` in `/Applications/GitNub.app/Contents/Resources/TexturedWindow.rb` (as in this commit: http://github.com/Caged/gitnub/commit/b23158d8483762fb849fe477233ce6851fbf8e8d) did the trick!